# INITCAP function with few exceptions

Tags: sql, oracle

Hey i have requirement to initcap the column name; with exception for few strings.

```
Source
THE BANK OF AMERICA
BANK OF BARODA
SEABANK OF INDIA

target
The BANK Of America
BANK Of Baroda
SeaBANK of INDIA
```

in this case i want t Initcap the incoming string but i need to retain the "BANK" value  and "INDIA" as is.

Comment: +1 for a well-specified question! Except that the 3rd target should be `SeaBANK Of INDIA`, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(initcap('THE BANK OF AMERICA 
BANK OF BARODA 
SEABANK OF INDIA'), 'Bank', 'BANK'), 'India', 'INDIA'),'bank', 'BANK') 
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (
          REGEXP_REPLACE (INITCAP ('SEABANK OF INDIA'), '(B|b)ank', 'BANK'),
          '(I|i)ndia',
          'INDIA')
  FROM DUAL;
```

Output:

> SeaBANK Of INDIA