# How do I search and replace upper case words with proper case equivalent

Tags: regex, text, oracle11g, uppercase

I'm using Oracle 11.g
I have a table with several clob columns of text data.  Each column contains at least a paragraph of text.  Almost every column has at least one occurrence of an uppercase word.  In every instance, those upper case words should be changed to mixed case (e.g. HELLO to Hello).  How do I find upper case words and change them to iniital caps?  I can't seem to find an example of this with regular expressions.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This thread might be useful for you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746959/initcap-function-with-few-exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE TAB_NAME SET CLOB_COLUMN_NAME=INITCAP(CLOB_COLUMN_NAME) --U CAN CHANGED ALL WORD TO INITCAP FORMAT .IF U WANT TO CHOOSE SOME WORD TO CONVERT INITCAP THEN MUST WRITE A USER DEFINED STORED FUNCTION.